# Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0 on M1 MacBook

Tags: python, keras

I am unable to identify this Warning Below.
I am using M1 MacBook Air

**CODE**

```
from keras import models
from keras.layers import Dense

model=models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu',input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16,activation='sigmoid'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Metal device set to: Apple M1
2021-09-24 18:18:51.205006: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:305] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2021-09-24 18:18:51.205728: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:271] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
```

Does it mean I am not using GPU of m1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Apple silicon is UMA, not NUMA. It's a unified memory architecture.  So ignore this message.  TF will work despite this annoying informational message.

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Apple silicon uses unified memory.  Memory is shared by the different subsystems of the system on a chip.  NUMA is non-uniform memory architecture.  That's when the CPU has RAM, and the GPU has VRAM, for example.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is very clear. Could be worth adding to original response even. Thanks!

Comment: That should be non-unified memory architecture for NUMA.  I think spell check messed it up.

Answer (score 1):

You are running on GPU but you may find issues if you try and use the Adam optimiser.  If you do try SGD instead.

You can add %GPU and GPU Time to the Activity Monitor if you want to check you are using GPU when training.